# Why recursion doesn't return value

Tags: python

Can't understand why this function return `None` instead of `filename`

```
import os
def existence_of_file():
    filename = str(input("Give me the name: "))
    if os.path.exists(filename):
        print("This file is already exists")
        existence_of_file()
    else:
        print(filename)
        return filename
a = existence_of_file()
print(a)
```

Output:

```
Give me the name: app.py
This file is already exists
Give me the name: 3.txt
3.txt
None
```

Comment: This should not use recursion. That should just be done in a loop.

Comment: You didn't return the result of the recursive call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must actually return the return value when calling the function again for recursion. This way, once you stop calling, you return correctly. It's returning `None` because the call returned nothing. Take a look at this cycle:

```
Asks for file -> Wrong one given -> Call again -> Right one given -> Stop recursion
```

Once you stop the recursion, the `filename` is returned to the the line where you recursively called the function, but it does nothing, so you're function returns `None`. You must add return. Change the recursive call to:

```
return existence_of_file()
```

This will yield:

```
>>>
Give me the name: bob.txt
This file is already exists
Give me the name: test.txt
test.txt
test.txt
```

Here's the full code:

```
import os
def existence_of_file():
    filename = str(input("Give me the name: "))
    if os.path.exists(filename):
        print("This file is already exists")
        return existence_of_file()
    else:
        print(filename)
        return filename
a = existence_of_file()
print(a)
```